# Passing a global var to a vue component attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass php/laravel data to my component from a custom global variable. I've seen examples of this going into the `new Vue({})` area directly but I haven't seen any way to pass this by going into right into the component

```
<script>
var itemData = //json object
</script>

<custom-component item-data="ITEMDATAVAR"></custom-component>
```

I should specify that I do have `item-data` in my component props. The issue is that I'm not sure how to tell my component's html that I'm passing the value of the variable `itemData` and not the string `"itemData"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to dynamic props

```
<custom-component v-bind:item-data="ITEMDATAVAR"></custom-component>
```

or use the shorthand syntax

```
<custom-component :item-data="ITEMDATAVAR"></custom-component>
```

Comment: Yup! Directly passing the json was giving me trouble but adding ":" fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can research this Vue.js [example](http://vuejs.org/examples/modal.html)

Create a variable

```
new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: yourJsonObject
})
```

In you component you have to write about props

```
Vue.component('custom-component', {
    props: ['item-data']
    ...
}
```

Pass the data to the component the same way

```
<custom-component item-data="ITEMDATAVAR"></custom-component>
```

I have not tested how it will work, guided by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `item-data` to the [`props`](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props) array like this:

```
Vue.component('custom-component', {

  props: ['item-data'],

  ...

}
```